# How can you fix an expired SSL certificate that has been using Http Strict-Transport-Security?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Effectively users cannot use the site that has been enforcing a very long HTST life-time header, because  SSL certificate of that site has expired. Because HTST headers are sitting in the browsers of users, how  is it possible to fix the issue and grant them access on simple HTTP?

Note: it's common sense that it's not possible to set HTST max-age: 0 because a valid connection can no longer be established to send that header, as the certificate expired.

Comment: Surely all you have to do is renew the certificate?

Comment: @EJP You can do it using another Certificate Authority from the previous one? (If so, then letting a certificate slip into expiration can cause you huge problems if someone else gets it prior to you?)

Comment: I don't know what any of this means. Nobody else can 'get' your certificate 'prior to you' or otherwise. You seem to be just inventing difficulties where none exist.